# How to use the same function to get the different output of two dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

I am looking to run one function to get two different outputs for two dictionaries, but I got the same output for the two dictionaries. I would be happy if you can review the code below and advise me how to get different output if I run the same function twice.

This is my code:

```
import csv
import time
import datetime
import math
import operator
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

from datetime import datetime

fn = 'screenviewclean.1.csv'

f = open(fn,"r")

reader = csv.reader(f)

mhist1= {}

def fun2_SctreenView (se,se1,l,m):

    for line in reader:
        l+=1
        sec1= line [10]
        IpAddress1 = line [2]
        timeStamp1 = line [6]
        time = timeStamp1[11:13]+ timeStamp1[13:19]
        Day =  timeStamp1[0:10]
        if l>1:
            if float(line[10]) > float(se) and float(line[10]) <= float(se1):
                if IpAddress1 in mhist1.keys():
                    mhist1[IpAddress1].append(str(time))
                else:
                    mhist1[IpAddress1] = [str (time)]
        m+=1 
    return mhist1

mhist1 = fun2_SctreenView (21600,43200,0,0)

mhist2 = fun2_SctreenView (43200,64800,0,0)
```

This is the sample of the csv file:

Unnamed: 0  lastLoggedVersion   IpAddress   deviceId    deviceOS    userId timeStamp    screenName  userType    doc.id  seconds

0   1.6.0.1 192.168.0.77    7612F62D-E392-4269-B49B-4F1214AA3888    iOS13.6.1   5U1XW8wkoqUPCTGhC1ni9Whinvt1    2020-11-13 22:28:55.029000+00:00    StudentProfile  student 00mrvPyS9Y2Al9iTN1vw    1231534.547

2   1.6.1.44    10.0.2.16   40a4dc7cb837fdec    Android10   27lFw6EnfbYFsU3F8AEejYGQRRl1    2020-11-12 21:28:00.998000+00:00    CompanySettings company 01dMOvAgsRTPSWXTDXIh    1141480.516

Comment: What is expected and actual output?

Comment: The expected and actual output --> mhist1 = {} amd mhist2 = 
{'10.48.18.47': ['07:46:06']}. I got this output when I run only one of those two functions separately.

Comment: But when I run both of those functions I got --> mhist1 = {} and mhist2 = {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-read the csv file in your reader variable every time you call the function. Put

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
```

inside you function, before running the loop. If you read it only once, the next time you read from the same variable, you end with empty result since the reader returned all the lines in the previous function call.

Without the csv, another suggestion could be to refer to the global dictionary you declared properly inside the function:

```
global mhist1
```

You don't need to return this variable anymore, the function will modify the global dictionary in-place.

Comment: I got the same thing, that what I did --> def fun2_SctreenView (se,se1,l,m):
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:

Comment: Post your sample csv as well.

Comment: I posted a sample csv

Comment: Please post the actual content - at-least one or two lines in the question rather than an image. Also, checkout the edit.

Comment: I did that, I posted two lines from the csv file

Comment: Do you mean to refer to the global dictionary like that --> def fun2_SctreenView (se,se1,l,m):
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    global mhist1
    for line in reader:

Comment: Yes, a separate line with content: `global mhist1`

Comment: if not, I would be happy if you can re-post the code that I posted with a few changing that you advise me to do to see if it will work?

Comment: I got the same thing

Comment: There is some issue in your conditional as well. The else block is never executed.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I removed the else block

Comment: Do you advise me to repose the same code with your suggestions? I think that this will help you to fix all issues in that code and advise me if there is any other things I need to fix it

Comment: You should fix the logic regarding else block first, none of the values in your csv are between the inputs se and se1 you provide.

Comment: I made filtration because on the "seconds" variable in the dataset. se and se1 indicate to the range of values which I am looking to take into consideration when I do filtration of the data.

Comment: Then try setting your arguments such that at-least for one of the lines in your csv, the else block is executed.

Comment: Could you please give me an example in what I should change in my code?

Comment: This code is running well without using the "function" and I faced this problem only when I tried to use the same function for different arguments.